# NGINX - Log shows segfault errors from libc-2.23.so

Tags: nginx

We've recently adapted FPM and NGINX on our server running Ubuntu 16.04. We've configured FPM and NGINX to the best of our abilities, but during stress testing, we're seeing unusual errors in the syslog file.

```
Mar 14 15:09:07 preprod kernel: [744222.773760] nginx[22589]: segfault at 557a0bf09100 ip 00007f214b88e52f sp 00007ffcbfd3d450 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f214b80c000+1c0000]

Mar 14 15:09:10 preprod kernel: [744225.439276] nginx[22609]: segfault at 557a0bfa78c0 ip 00007f214b88e52f sp 00007ffcbfd3cf70 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f214b80c000+1c0000]

Mar 14 15:09:12 preprod kernel: [744227.707396] nginx[22287]: segfault at 5579a7016288 ip 00007f214b88e52f sp 00007ffcbfd3d5a0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f214b80c000+1c0000]

Mar 14 15:09:12 preprod kernel: [744227.790616] nginx[22610]: segfault at 557a0c045210 ip 00007f214b88e52f sp 00007ffcbfd3cd60 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f214b80c000+1c0000]

Mar 14 15:09:14 preprod kernel: [744229.909503] nginx[22638]: segfault at 557a0bf91960 ip 00007f214b88e52f sp 00007ffcbfd3d370 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f214b80c000+1c0000]

Mar 14 15:09:21 preprod kernel: [744236.728542] nginx[22671]: segfault at 557a0bfce230 ip 00007f214b88a478 sp 00007ffcbfd3d3e0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f214b80c000+1c0000]
```

I upgraded NGINX to the latest stable version, hoping that it would fix the issue. Unfortunately, it still appears to be crashing. I then configured NGINX to write a dump file to /tmp/, but when I run gdb followed by "bt" I only see the following output...:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3bb4d2c428 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f3bb4d2e02a in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

EDIT: The output of GDB BT is below...:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3bb4d2c428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at 
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007f3bb4d2e02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007f3bb4d6e7ea in __libc_message (do_abort=2, 
fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f3bb4e87ed8 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
   at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007f3bb4d77dfb in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=0x7f3bb50bbb20 
<main_arena>, ptr=0x555ca9650fe0, str=0x7f3bb4e84c75 "corrupted size vs. prev_size",
   action=3) at malloc.c:5006
#4  _int_free (av=0x7f3bb50bbb20 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, 
have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4014
#5  0x00007f3bb4d7b53c in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at 
malloc.c:2968
#6  0x0000555ca82ef537 in ngx_destroy_pool ()
#7  0x0000555ca8330ce1 in ngx_http_free_request ()
#8  0x0000555ca836a0bb in ngx_http_v2_close_stream ()
#9  0x0000555ca8344d45 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000555ca8343e3f in ?? ()
#11 0x0000555ca8319d94 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000555ca830ed2a in ngx_process_events_and_timers ()
#13 0x0000555ca8317bb5 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000555ca8315fce in ngx_spawn_process ()
#15 0x0000555ca8317260 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000555ca83188fd in ngx_master_process_cycle ()
#17 0x0000555ca82ecbfe in main ()
```

I'm not sure what to do. We began troubleshooting from the start because we saw intermittent connection errors, and the NGINX / FPM logs didn't show very much.

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the server on which you are running this software?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is a DigitalOcean node running Ubuntu 16.04 with 48GB of RAM and 12 cores. NGINX appears to be the only thing crashing.

Comment: Hmm. Check that you don't have corrupted package files, e.g. `sudo debsums -c`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just ran sudo debsums -c as instructed, and it finished but didn't output any alerts. I'm assuming it passed then.

Comment: Strange. This sort of thing generally has two causes: either the binaries are corrupted, or the physical hardware is defective (e.g. bad RAM). Being a virtual machine, to test the other one is not going to be within your capability. You should have a chat with DO about live migrating your VM to another physical server.